# Find which SQL queries take a lot of CPU

Tags: mysql, sql, debian

Is there a way to detect queries that use a lot of CPU ?

I know how to detect long queries but don't know if its possible to detect queries that take mass CPU.

Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/slow-query-log.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iam not sure what you mean,but with `microtime` you can find out which query was taken more time for execution like this

```
$sql='...';
$start=microtime(true);
$mysql_query($sql);
$end=microtime(true)-$start;
echo $end.' seconds'; // in seconds
echo ($end*1000).' milliseconds';
```